# Mail Blocked By Spanhaus

Tags: email, server, smtp

I made an SMTP server in microsoft server 2016. But when i go to send mail through powershell to an email address. The mail goes to queue or bad list. It give me the error:

```
Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 10:37:03 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01D31BE72DD4ACEE00000008mail.frezee.uk"
X-DSNContext: 7ce717b1 - 1196 - 00000002 - 00000000
Message-ID: <yWtIIZS2T00000005@mail.frezee.uk>
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

This is a MIME-formatted message.  
Portions of this message may be unreadable without a MIME-capable mail program.

--9B095B5ADSN=_01D31BE72DD4ACEE00000008mail.frezee.uk
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=unicode-1-1-utf-7

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

       jameswheeler54@hotmail.co.uk




--9B095B5ADSN=_01D31BE72DD4ACEE00000008mail.frezee.uk
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns;mail.frezee.uk
Received-From-MTA: dns;WIN-NM193HJ6M6C
Arrival-Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 10:37:03 +0100

Final-Recipient: rfc822;jameswheeler54@hotmail.co.uk
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [90.255.57.31] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso (AS3130).
```

Anyone know what i am doing wrong? I have an a record for mail pointing to the servers ip.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

- request removal on the given url
- don't send too much email to 1 provider at once ( send 5-10 then pause until your spam-score decreases, then may be more ... )

Answer (score 0):

Your IP is assigned from a pool of addresses of a consumer ISP. You can request to be removed from the whitelist, but likely it will end up there again as very likely is abused by spammers.

```
inetnum:        90.255.32.0 - 90.255.63.255
netname:        VODAFONE-DYN-IP
descr:          Dynamic IP Addresses
descr:          Vodafone Consumer Broadband
```

You can attempt to use a proxy to mask your IP hoping that the public IP will not be blacklisted, or you can attempt to reset the router in order to get assigned another public IP which is not blacklisted. However, the real solution would be to contact your ISP and request to have assigned a static IP address, but likely this is available for business contracts only or you have to pay an additional fee for it.